# How to deploy source controller code, and not rely on bin DLL in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

While testing I need to deploy source controller files and relevant Views, rather than the whole project dll. I would then hope that thhe ASP.NET runtime would then do its JIT compilation.

I do use a file comparison tool called Beyond Compare which ensures that the changed files are identified and copied across.

Views are kept in source anyway, but it seems controller code is expected to be in the DLL which gives me issues when I have other code which I do not wish to deploy.

How can I do this ?

Many thanks.

Comment: The question is not _how_, but _why_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we deploy an asp.net MVC application by copying the source codes (without compiling) like we can do when deploying a WebForm website proj?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501649/can-we-deploy-an-asp-net-mvc-application-by-copying-the-source-codes-without-co)

Comment: @CodeCaster, Thanks for this. The reason I was investigating this is that I have breaking changes in another part of the same project, hence those changes would appear in the same dll. Hence the reason for hoping to just copy the files of interest.

Comment: That's what source control and branching are for. :-)

Comment: OK, OK, perhaps I need to get into GIT.... One of my other tasks :)

Comment: It appears the answer is no from your provided link.

Comment: If you provide an answer then I will accept. Huge thanks.

Comment: I stand corrected, see @Andy's answer.

Comment: I've flagged the other question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer ([Can we deploy an asp.net MVC application by copying the source codes (without compiling) like we can do when deploying a WebForm website proj?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501649/can-we-deploy-an-asp-net-mvc-application-by-copying-the-source-codes-without-co)) was incorrect. You can, in fact, have your controller code live in the App_Code folder. You have to make sure that you manage your namespaces. For example, if you follow the regular convention of no namespace for a class defined in App_Code, you need to explicitly include a String.Empty namespace in your route configuration:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new String[] { String.Empty }
    );
```

Comment: Huge thanks for this. Interesting that I have 2 close votes based on the fact that this is a duplicate of an incorrect answer !!! Many thanks for your enlightenment. Also a big thank you CodeCaster for raising the issue of Source Control.

Comment: @SamJolly I close-voted because the other question asks the same question, and the answer is pretty sure in mentioning it can't be done. It is an upvoted and accepted answer, which _to me_ is enough to flag it as duplicate, as who am I to second-guess that? :-)

Comment: My thanks as well, CodeCaster; I added an answer to the referenced question with an explanation of how one had to "encourage" MVC to behave. :)